# Image appears to be flickering due to caching on iOS using Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, caching, parse-platform, uiimage

I am having issues with my tableviewcell's image appearing to flicker. I know what is causing the issue, I am just not sure of the best way to get around it.

I am using Parse.

The flickering is caused by using the cache policy CacheThenNetwork, so the query checks the cache and then checks the network for any changes. This results in the query being run multiple times, and therefore the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called multiple times.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, I set the image to nil to avoid duplicate images when the cells are dequeued. This is one of the main reasons that the flickering happens, and if it wasn't set to nil then the image wouldn't be disappearing and appearing again each time the query is called.

So my question is, is there a better way to handle the caching or the cellForRowAtIndexPath so that I can avoid this apparent flickering?

I need to use this particular cache policy as it works best for what I am doing. I also need to avoid the duplicate images, so setting the image to nil works for me. If theres a better way of doing this though, please advise!

Thanks in advance.

Code snippets below.

```
-(void)loadTimeline
{
    NSLog(@"Loading timeline");
    PFQuery *loadTimeline = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Timeline"];
    [loadTimeline whereKey:@"objectId" notEqualTo:@""];
    loadTimeline.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    //[loadTimeline clearCachedResult];
    [loadTimeline orderByDescending:@"timestamp"];
    [loadTimeline findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             _timelineArray = [NSMutableArray new];

             // Look through all objects in Timeline table
             for (PFObject *object in objects)
             {
                 // For every object in the timeline, check the current user's favourites
                 for (PFObject *favourite in [[Engine sharedInstance] favouritesArray])
                 {
                     if ([[object valueForKey:@"club_objectId"] isEqualToString:[favourite valueForKey:@"club_objectId"]])
                     {
                         [_timelineArray addObject:object];
                     }
                 }

                 // If post is a Sporter announcement, add it to the array
                 if ([[object valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"sporter_announcement"])
                 {
                     [_timelineArray addObject:object];
                 }
             }
             [[self tableView] reloadData];
         }
     }];
}
```

Image being set in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
// Club badge image
        [cell.clubBadgeButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        PFFile *badgeImageFile = object[@"badge_image"];
        [badgeImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                UIImage *badgeImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                [cell.clubBadgeButton setImage:badgeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not download the images once and store in the cache folder of the application data storage? This way you can avoid the costly network call to get the same image each time. Implementing a unique filename or other reference would allow you to re-download ONLY when the image has changed. Otherwise it can be cached locally by the OS and only purged if the system has to reclaim the space.